# How to distinguish Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2

Tags: c#

I need to distinguish Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 but I don't know how to. The OS Version property return the same number "6.1.7600.0"

Regards,

Florian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [GetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358.aspx), Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 have different Product Type numbers.

[image]

[Source](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/system/article.php/c8973)

Comment: For information, with a Windows 2008 R2 Standard Edition, the Product Type value returned by the GetProductInfo is 7 (and no 3)

Comment: Are these product type masks also found in the registry?

Comment: @jlafay: I don't think so, the GetProductInfo method is part of Kernel32.lib, so I'd imagine they were hard-coded into the Kernel32.dll, but don't quote me on that ;)

Comment: Important addition (spent hours to understand the problem): Product type can return as 2 as well for windows server 2008 / 2008 r2 IF set to be domain controller (dcpromo)

Answer (score 1):

You might find this useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/osversion.aspx

OSProductType on that should be Server