# Problem with checking the Windows version from Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, windowsversion

My program installs a driver, which has different versions compiled for XP, Win2003, Vista/Win2008, and Win7. I use pascal functions to check which is the OS, and install the corresponding DLL.

On some users' systems no DLL is installed, which means all the functions have returned false. This should not happen so long as the OS's major version is 5 or 6.

Can anyone tell me if there is something wrong with the code I use?

```
[Code]
function UseDriverForWindows7(): Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  // Windows 7 version is 6.1 (workstation)
  if (Version.Major = 6)  and
     (Version.Minor = 1) and
     (Version.ProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
  then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;

function UseDriverForWindowsVistaAndWindows2008(): Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  // Anything with major version 6 where we won't use Windows 7 driver
  if (Version.Major = 6) and
     (not UseDriverForWindows7)
  then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;

function UseDriverForWindows2003(): Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  // Windows 2003 version is 5.2 (server)
  if (Version.Major = 5)  and
     (Version.Minor = 2)  and
     (Version.ProductType <> VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
  then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;

function UseDriverForWindowsXP(): Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  // Anything with major version 5 where we won't use Windows 2003 driver
  if (Version.Major = 5) and
     (not UseDriverForWindows2003)
  then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;

[Files]
Source: "mydrv-xp-x86.dll"; DestDir: {app}; DestName: mydrv.dll; Check: not IsWin64 and UseDriverForWindowsXP; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "mydrv-2003-x86.dll"; DestDir: {app}; DestName: mydrv.dll; Check: not IsWin64 and UseDriverForWindows2003; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "mydrv-vista-x86.dll"; DestDir: {app}; DestName: mydrv.dll; Check: not IsWin64 and UseDriverForWindowsVistaAndWindows2008; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "mydrv-win7-x86.dll"; DestDir: {app}; DestName: mydrv.dll; Check: not IsWin64 and UseDriverForWindows7; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "mydrv-xp-x64.dll"; DestDir: {app}; DestName: mydrv.dll; Check: IsWin64 and UseDriverForWindows2003; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "mydrv-vista-x64.dll"; DestDir: {app}; DestName: mydrv.dll; Check: IsWin64 and UseDriverForWindowsVistaAndWindows2008; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "mydrv-win7-x64.dll"; DestDir: {app}; DestName: mydrv.dll; Check: IsWin64 and UseDriverForWindows7; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Comment: I suppose you've looked into using `OnlyBelowVersion` instead of your custom code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [common parameters](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_commonparams.htm) `MinVersion` and `OnlyBelowVersion` in conjunction with the function [`IsWin64`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_iswin64.htm).

### Update

To distinguish between workstation and server versions you can use the [`GetWindowsVersionEx`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getwindowsversionex.htm) function which is integrated in Inno Setup.

Comment: How do I distinguish between workstation vs server OS using these? Win2008 and Win7 both are 6.1 AFAIK, but I need to install a different driver for each.

Comment: @satuon: see [How to distinguish Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3839572/256544)